# How to assign dynamic values within codes in react

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-vis, react-vis-network

I am using react-vis-network to create graphs. below is the syntax to use react-vis-network.

```
const MyNetwork = () => (
  <Network>
    <Node id='vader' label='Darth Vader' decorator={Decorator} />
    <Node id='luke' label='Luke Skywalker' decorator={Decorator} />
    <Node id='leia' label='Leia Organa' decorator={Decorator} />
    <Edge id='1' from='vader' to='luke' />
    <Edge id='1' from='vader' to='leia' />
  </Network>
);
```

i would like assign dynamic values to 'id' and 'label'. I tried below also {n.name}without codes("). both the options are not working.

```
<Network>
{data.Application.map(n => {
  return (
       <Node id ="{n.name}" label="{n.name}" />
          );
            })}
</Network>
```

can someone advise me on how to pass dynamic values within codes to the variables id and label

Comment: Doesn't `id ={n.name}` work?

Comment: nope, id= {n.name} didn't work. when i try id="{n.name}", the value is taken as constant :(

Comment: SORRY, id = {n.name} does work.. i should have tried with typo earlier :(